# positioning an element relatively to other elements

Tags: html, css

i have an element (span) that i want to place in the right of main element(text input). the main element is centered in a parent div. if position the span absolute, it relates to the parent div and not to the input, and if i position the span relative it moves the input from the middle of the parent and starts at the left side of the input(and i want it to be at the left side and without moving him) i don't want to position the span relatively to the parent because the input size is changing in scroll.
by the way my whole web is direction: rtl, and if i change it so the span is to the right side of the input but still moving it from the center, and i don't want to change tohe direction of the other elements in my web.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  direction: rtl;
}
.main_div{
   background: red;
  margin: auto;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   width:400px;
  height: 600px;
 }
input{ 
  margin: 30px auto;
}
span.titles{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main_div">
      <form>
        <span class="titles">input 1</span><span>the additional span</span><input type="text">
        <span class="titles">input 2</span><input type="text">
        <p>i want input 1 to be in the center and the additional span to go more left and i want it to be dynamic like always 5px space to the right of the input.
        thenks
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Solved. I used a table.